# yum update shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell-script, bash-scripting

I am new liunx Scripting can anybody help me with a script for yum update where we want to update all the packages linux without rebooting.(excluding kernel and important packages which require reboot)

Comment: To my knowledge (I could be wrong) - even if you did update the Kernel - it does not force a reboot. It will simply schedule to use the new kernel on reboot (when you finally did decided to reboot). So you can update as you want and reboot when you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the Information, can i get any bash script to run.

Answer (score 0):

yum update will not cause a reboot, whatever packages you update/install. 
However, to answer your question, yes you can exclude packages from yum installation :

- permanently in /etc/yum.conf (see man yum.conf)
- in command-line with --exclude=package option (see man yum)

Comment: can i get any script do run yum update

Comment: What do you mean? you just need to type "yum update" from a terminal. What distro are you using: centos, rhel, other?